# What Happens when we do visible property to false

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

IDE  : Visual Studio
Programming: C# .net

Today While doing programming one question arise in my mind what happens when we do

```
Form1 f1 = new Form1();
f1.show();
this.hide();
//this.visible = false;
```

Tell me what exactly happens in memory when we apply this code. the instance is removed in memory or it remains in memory ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference at all. Look how `Hide` method is implemented:

```
public void Hide()
{
    this.Visible = false;
}
```

> Now Tell me what exactly happens in memory when we apply this code.
>   **the instance is removed in memory or it remains in memory?**

Detail logic under `Visible` property setter is not that simple, but it definitely stays in memory, because you can always do `Visible = true` and show it again.

Comment: Before moving to another form I want to save this instance somewhere can u suggest me how to store?

Answer (score 1):

They are equivalent.  From the documentation for [Control.Hide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.hide.aspx):

> Hiding the control is equivalent to
>   setting the Visible property to false.

You can confirm this with reflector:

```
public void Hide()
{
    this.Visible = false;
}
```

You might use Show() or Hide() when you know the value and use Visible when you take the visibility in as a parameter, although personally I would always use Visible.